# Use one docker container or many (from withing python)?

Tags: python, docker, performance

Using a containerised process. Calling it from a python script. Executing the process each time by doing:

`subprocess.Popen(["docker run (flags here) (image here) (command here)" ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`

This creates yet another container instance. It runs and then stops.
Using `docker ps -a` you can see all the thousands of stopped containers. Is this bad?
Should we use a single container to run all these commands?
What is the best practice for using a single container? Should we simply run a sleep command and then get that container ID and use it for all the calls?
Again, we're using Python to start the containerized process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clean up the containers after you're done with them, yes.

In the code you have, include a `docker run --rm` option.  This will immediately delete the container once it exits.  (If it fails, and you would have wanted to review the logs, they'll be gone.)  You could explicitly `docker rm` the containers if you prefer.

You should probably be using the [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to launch the containers.  (`subprocess.Popen(shell=True)` is extremely risky security-wise, especially when you're trying to run a command like `docker run` with the real potential of rooting the host; in general, avoid the `subprocess` module when you can use a Python-native library to do the same task.)  If you do this, then you can launch the container with

```python
container = client.containers.run('image', 'command', auto_remove=True)
```

There's nothing intrinsically wrong with spinning up as many containers as you need to do your work (though you may find it faster, simpler, and safer to use a non-container local process).  I'd consider this better than doing something artificial to "keep the container alive" so you can use debugging tools like `docker exec` to launch additional commands in it.

Comment: Yup, that sounds great. Thanks for pointing out the SDK. I was looking for it on Google and all the results that came up were about creating a containers/image for a Python app. Thank you for the high quality informative answer.